# how to get the most representative features in the following tfidf model?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

Hello I have the following list:

```
listComments = ["comment1","comment2","comment3",...,"commentN"]
```

I created a tfidf vectorizer to get a model from my comments as follows:

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=10,ngram_range=(1,3),analyzer='word')
tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(listComments)
```

Now in order to undestand more about my model I would like to get the most representative features, I tried:

```
print("these are the features :",tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())
print("the vocabulary :",tfidf_vectorizer.vocabulary_)
```

and this is giving me a list of words that I think that my model is using for the vectorization:

```
these are the features : ['10', '10 days', 'red', 'car',...]

the vocabulary : {'edge': 86, 'local': 96, 'machine': 2,...}
```

However I would like to find a way to get the 30 most representative features, I mean the words that achieves the highest values in my tfidf model, the words with highest inverse frecuency, I was Reading in the documentation but I was not able to find this method I really appreciate help with this issue, thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a list of the vocabulary with respect to idf scores you can use the `idf_` attribute and `argsort` it.

```
# create an array of feature names
feature_names = np.array(tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names())

# get order
idf_order = tfidf_vectorizer.idf_.argsort()[::-1]

# produce sorted idf word
feature_names[idf_order]
```

If you would like to get a sorted list of tfidf scores for each document you would do a similar thing.

```
# get order for all documents based on tfidf scores
tfidf_order = tfidf.toarray().argsort()[::-1]

# produce words
feature_names[tfidf_order]
```